# The method 'retype' isn't defined for the class 'Stream<T>' (rx-dart)

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter project, i upgraded flutter to the latest version. Then suddenly the application stopped building and gives the error in the question.

Ive tried

```
flutter clean
flutter packages upgrade
flutter packages get
flutter doctor
```

Flutter doctor shows no errors

```
/Users/mac/Desktop/code/flutter/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.6-pre.30, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any ideas as to why the project isn't building?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to upgrade rxdart to the newest 0.18.0 version that works with the Dart version included in the Flutter version you are using.

Comment: This was the solution. flutter packages upgrade only upgraded to 0.16.7 and not to 0.18.0 which is the latest. Strange behavior. I manually set the version and it fixed

Comment: If the version constraint in `pubspec.yaml` doesn't allow the version, then `flutter packages upgrade` doesn't upgrade to newer versions. `^0.16.7` means all versions that match `0.16.x`. For versions >= `1.0.0` `^1.0.0` means `1.x.x`